# Flat file connection manager carriage return/line feed discrepancy

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2017

I'm upgrading from SQL Server 2008R2 to 2017, and making the same jump with SSIS. There are a number of flat file imports that are picking up files that have carriage return/line feeds (`{CR}{LF}`) embedded within a column in the row.

The 2008R2 flat file connection manager ignores the embedded `{CR}{LF}`s that are within a row, but the flat file connection manager in 2017 is treating each `{CR}{LF}` as a new line. It's the same in an upgraded connection manager or a brand new one that I make from scratch.

In both versions, the connection managers have the same specs:

```
General Tab

  Locale: English (United States)
  Unicode: No
  Code page: 1252 (ANSI-Latin I)
  Format: Delimited
  Text qualifier: <none>
  Header row delimiter: {CR}{LF}
  Header rows to skip: 0
  Column names in the first data row: Check

Columns Tab

  Row delimiter: {CR}{LF}
  Column delimiter: Vertical Bar{|}
```

The not particularly complicated text file I'm testing with:

```
row_id|row_data|empty_column|created_by|one_more_field{CR}{LF}
1|random test data||ebrandt|{CR}{LF}
2|Data field with a carriage return{CR}{LF}
and a line feed embedded in it.||ebrandt|
```

I pasted on the line terminators, just to show that they're there.

On the `Columns` tab, the Preview window in BIDS 2008R2 shows two rows:

[image: 2008R2_connectionmgr]

But in 2017, exactly the same file gets broken into three rows:

[image: 2017_connectionmgr]

There isn't bandwidth in this project to rework all the file imports.

Is there a setting that got changed between versions that I can change back? Or is there another trick to this that I'm missing?

**Edit:** In response to a comment that's been deleted, I would specify a text qualifier if I could, but the files I'm getting don't have any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Flat File Connection Manager you need to set the `AlwaysCheckForRowDelimiters` property to `False`.

Your file will then be parsed as before.

This was a change made in 2012 to change behaviour to [the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/flat-file-connection-manager?view=sql-server-2017).

> By default, the Flat File connection manager always checks for a row
>   delimiter in unquoted data, and starts a new row when a row delimiter
>   is found. This enables the connection manager to correctly parse files
>   with rows that are missing column fields.

See [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2013/03/13/flat-file-source-cannot-handle-file-with-uneven-number-of-columns-in-each-row/) for more about it.