# How to combine two rows into one row with respective column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've a csv file which contains data with new lines for a single row i.e. one row data comes in two lines and I want to insert the new lines data into respective columns. I've loaded the data into sql but now I want to replace the second row data into 1st row with respective column values.

[image]

output details:

[image]

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. What is the current state of your database table with respect to the record in question? That is, does the record where `id=3` have `NULL` in the last four columns? And do you have a record with `id IS NULL` and `Name='2016-03-08`, etc.? Or are you trying to import the bad data from scratch?

Comment: Hi Dashier, In my csv file I've data with CRLF for id 3 i.e. ID 3 data comes in new line and when I import data from csv to sql I get the data as mentioned in the table above but I want the new line col values to be inserted/updated into ID 3 respective columns and the black row should be deleted finally...this will be same for ID 5 too.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend fixing this in SQL because this is an issue with the CSV file. The issue is that file contains new lines, which causes rows split.

I strongly encourage fixing CSV files, if possible. It's going to be difficult to fix that in SQL given there are going to be more cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the import with SSIS (or if you have the option of doing it with SSIS if you are not currently), the package can be configured to manage embedded carriage returns.

Define your file import connection manager with the columns you're expecting.

In the connection manager's Properties window, set the `AlwaysCheckForRowDelimiters` property to `False`. The default value is `True`.

By setting the property to `False`, SSIS will ignore mid-row carriage return/line feeds and will parse your data into the required number of columns.

Credit to Martin Smith for [helping me out when I had a very similar problem some time ago.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951062/flat-file-connection-manager-carriage-return-line-feed-discrepancy)

Comment: Yes I'm importing through SSIS

Comment: Excellent. Give the Properties change a try and see if it helps!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. If you could take a moment to click the grey check mark to the left to accept the answer, I'd be most appreciative!